# Flutter - The replay icon is nowhere to be seen after the video is finished

Tags: flutter, dart

My goal is when the video has finished playing then an icon **replay** should be seen for the user to click and the video will start again. I did it before but when I added **opacity** it's nowhere to be seen.

```
double level = 1.0;

void _opacity() {
    void _iconOpacity() {
    setState(() {
      level = level == 0.0 ? 1.0 : 0.0;
    });
  }
 }
```

```
AnimatedOpacity(
          opacity: level,
          //when user clicks, the icon will hide 
          duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
          child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => setState(() {
              if (videoFinished) {
                _vidController.seekTo(Duration.zero);
                _vidController.play();
                setState(() {
                  videoFinished = false;
                });
              } else if (_vidController.value.isPlaying) {
                _vidController.pause();
                _iconOpacity();
              } else {
                _vidController.play();
                _iconOpacity();
              }
            }),
            child: Center(
              child: videoFinished
                  ? Icon(Icons.replay, color: Colors.green)
                  : (_vidController.value.isPlaying)
                      ? Icon(Icons.pause, color: Colors.green)
                      : Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: Colors.green),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Hi. Where do you use `_changeOpacity`? isn't it unused?

Comment: Hi. I already fixed it. Thank you! the problem is still the same.